# In robots.txt, what will Disallow: /?s block?

Tags: search-engine, web-crawler, robots.txt

What will this line block when the search engine crawls the website?

Disallow: /?s

Answer (score 1):

It will block robots from crawling any URLs (in the root (?)) that they stumble upon that contain `s` in their query strings.